# Blocked ip's from iptables to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, iptables

Dealing with `iptables` and php / mysql but no luck, I'm trying to find an solution to add blocked ip's ( yes, more than one at once ) from `iptables` to mysql. Is anyone able to help with this issue?

```
<?php
    $hostname = gethostname();
    $name = permanent;
    require_once("/etc/blocked/inc/config.inc.php");

    $output = shell_exec('iptables -S permanent');
    $lines=explode("\n",$output);
    $fail=array();
    $r="/(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/";
    foreach($lines as $line){

      $t=array();
      preg_match($r,$line,$t);
      $ip=$t[0];
      $fail[0]=$ip;

      if ($fail[0] == '') {
      }
      else {

        #echo "$hostname,$fail[0],$name \n";

        $query = "INSERT INTO blockedips (hostname,ip,name) VALUES ('$hostname','$fail[0]','$name')" ;

        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('Query failed: ' .       mysqli_error($link));

        mysqli_close($link);
        exit;
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What does `$output` contain and what errors do you get?

Comment: I bet someone could help if they knew what the issue was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I've got some time to kill. I suggest you read up on how to use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), as well as reconsider how you're treating your database connection. I also corrected a bunch of other small mistakes and needless code.

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostname();
// this needs to be quoted
$name = "permanent";
require_once("/etc/blocked/inc/config.inc.php");
// specify the full path to your binary
$output = exec("/sbin/iptables -S permanent", $lines);
// exec will create an array
//$lines=explode("\n",$output);
// you weren't capturing the IP address here
$r="/((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))/";
foreach($lines as $line){
    // this can create itself
    // $t=array();
    // why aren't you checking the results of this call?
    if (preg_match($r, $line, $t)) {
        // $t[0] is the whole string, $t[1] is the first match
        $ip = $t[1];
        // I don't know why you were re-assigning this to another array
        // $fail[0]=$ip;
        #echo "$hostname,$ip,$name \n";
        $query = "INSERT INTO blockedips (hostname,ip,name) VALUES ('$hostname','$ip','$name')";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query)
            or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($link));
        // why close your database? your second query isn't going to work too well
        // mysqli_close($link);
        // oh, will never be a second value. is this intentional? why have a loop then?
        // exit;
    }
}
?>
```

But wait! [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) are made to be prepared once and executed repeatedly, while reducing system overhead. I'd also strongly suggest migrating to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), or at least use the [mysqli object-oriented interface](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php).

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostname();
$name = "permanent";
require_once("/etc/blocked/inc/config.inc.php");
$output = exec("/sbin/iptables -S $name", $lines);
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO blockedips (hostname,ip,name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$octet = "(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
$ip = "$octet\.$octet\.$octet\.$octet";
foreach($lines as $line){
    if (preg_match("/($ip)/", $line, $t)) {
        $ip = $t[1];
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $hostname, $ip, $name);
        if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
            echo 'Query failed: ' . $link->error();
            $link->close();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: WoW miken32 that works like a charm - many many thanks!
And with explanation! I'm impressed, thank you for this little Xmas gift!